# unable to set state after get request

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to change my state with the follwing data after fetch request but the state never changes after set state
[image]

```
profileinfo:
  {
    Firstname:'Jeff ',
    Lastname:'Series',
    email:'exam.com',
    Address:'502B Inner Circle Riverwalk'
  }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/login")
    .then(response=>response.json()
    .then(data=>(
        this.setState({profileinfo:data[0].firstname}))))
        console.log(this.state.profileinfo)
    }
```

Comment: In order to `setState()` work you need to have your entire state stored on an object called state, you are trying to update a state that doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the set state callback? it is possible that your state has not been updated yet when the console.log is hit.

maybe try

```
this.setState({profileinfo:data[0].firstname}, () => console.log(this.state.profileinfo))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a syntax. You need to close the bracket at `.then(response=>response.json()`

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/login")
  .then(response=>response.json()) // <-Insert a close bracket here
  .then(data=> this.setState({profileinfo:data[0].firstname}, () => console.log(this.state.profileinfo)) // <- Call console in callback
  ) // <- Remove one here
    console.log(this.state.profileinfo)
}
```

And call console in the callback function to get the right value. Because `setState` is an async function.

Comment: I guess it was the syntax ...Thanks